# How can I remove the "0" placeholder from <input type="number"> in Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, html, input, mobile-safari

I have an input field for users to input a monetary amount:

```
<input type="number" value="{{ order.amount }}" />
```

I chose the `number` input type because I want the number keyboard to appear when the field is clicked. I can't use `type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"` (suggested [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html))  because that causes the number-only input pad to appear which doesn't have a decimal point.

Unfortunately, if the `value` attribute is anything but numeric (including an empty string or space), the field renders with a default value of "0":

[image]

This stinks because the user needs to hit <kbd>⌫</kbd> before entering a value.

Is there any way to fix this?

**Update:** I'm an idiot. Some JavaScript was validating and reformatting the field. Nevermind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look at the code you are using to set the `value` attribute of this field (`value="{{ order.amount }}"`). The reason I say this is that in Mobile Safari a "vanilla" numeric field is empty, i.e. no `0` by default.

Your screenshot suggests to me that you're using jQuery Mobile, so I checked using that in case the issue lay there, but again, no default value of zero.

For what it's worth, this is the mark-up I'm using (which renders an empty number field in iOS emulators and on an iPhone 3GS):

```
<input type="number" value="" />
```

Comment: Odd. I tried this before asking and I see a 0 in my field. FWIW, my iPhone simulator version is 4.1.